# Using Java 8, how can you see space available to JVM from within an image?

Tags: java, docker, java-8, diskspace

Is there a way in Java8 to get disk space available to JVM within an image?
using
`javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getRoots()[0].getUsableSpace()`
this seems to give the available system space(which is much higher), instead of space within the image.

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not restrict available disk space. So inside disk space should be same as host.